# Send WhatsApp text message with image from Excel VBA on a MacBook

Tags: excel, vba, macos, whatsapp

The code below works fine on a Windows based computer.
Two issues with the following code:
1 For each WhatsApp message it opens a new tab (not that big of a deal but annoying)
2 Be able to run this on a Mac - Client has several MacBooks that they use along with Windows

```
For Each g In Range("rng_temp") ' Temp range set earlier based on number of tour guides needed
  '-- set text string
  sFName = Split(g.Value, " ")
  sFName = Trim(sFName(0)) '--- pull just the guides first name from the list
  
  sText = sFName & sWhatsAppText '-- string together name and WhatsApp text to send
  
  
  '-- extract guides tours
  Range("rng_GuideCrit").Value = g.Value
  GetEMailGuides '-- extract list of tours the current guide (g) is active
  '--- copy guide schedule to clipboard
  Range("rng_ExtractGuideTours").Select
  Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).CopyPicture , xlBitmap
  '--- get WhatsApp Phone Number
  whatsapp_number = Application.WorksheetFunction.XLookup(g.Value, Range("tbl_Guides[Guide]"), Range("tbl_Guides[Phone Number]"), "N/A")
 
 '-- create whats app text
  ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink "https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=%2B" & whatsapp_number & "&text=" & sText & "&app_absent=1&send=1"
    
    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:5"))
    
     #If Mac Then '--- this is the section where I need the help - It needs to be able to paste in a picture that is in the clipboard 
        AppleScript("tell application " & Chr(34) & "System Events" & Chr(34) & "to keystrke ""f"" using (command down)")
        AppleScript("tell application " & Chr(34) & "System Events" & Chr(34) & "to keystrke ""36""")
        
    #Else ' this works well on a Windows based computer
        Call SendKeys("^v") ', True
        Call SendKeys("{Enter}", True)
    #End If

    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    #If Mac Then '-- need to have it send the text
        AppleScript("tell application " & Chr(34) & "System Events" & Chr(34) & "to keystrke ""36""")
    #Else '-- again this works on Windows computer
        Call SendKeys("{Enter}", True)
    #End If
    Range("tbl_Tours[[#Headers],[Whats App Sent]]").Offset(i, 0).Value = "Yes" 'flags main table that WhatsApp message has been sent
    i = i + 1 'increments the counter for the next g loop
Next g
```

I have seen some old posts but have not been able to find what I need.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

While using a MacBook I am expecting the WhatsApp message to be sent.